# How to connect Parity to Miner using Stratum & LAN & solo mining?

Tags: mining, parity, claymore

I am testing Parity with Stratum (is in beta):

Parity is running and fully synchronized, on Foundation Chain, on a machine of the LAN (192.168.5.11), started on terminal with:

```
sudo parity --author 0037a6b811ffeb6e072da21179d11b1406371c63 --stratum --stratum-interface=0.0.0.0 --stratum-port=8008
```

Miner (Claymore) is working on the LAN (192.168.5.12) and started with:

```
sudo ./ethdcrminer64 -epool http://192.168.5.11:8008 -mode 1
```

Firewalls disabled on both Parity's and Miner's machines.

Miner reports not possible connect to http://192.168.5.11:8545

Miner is working fine in a pool. Just doing some tests with solo mining and my Parity Node.